# How to sum string values in pivot table?

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataset with various types of student data. I'm trying to create a pivot table that shows how many of each sex prefer a specific genre of music but right now it's just aggregating all of the M/F strings. This is the code I currently have:

```
pivot= df.pivot_table(index= 'Favorite_Music_Genre', values= 'Gender', aggfunc= 'sum')
```

And this is the output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eedX8.png)

I assume it has something to do with 'aggfunc'. Please help!

Comment: so you want the count of M and F, have you tried to replace `sum` by `count`

Comment: yes, that is what i meant sorry

Comment: you're welcome, happy to help!

Comment: please post a small sample of your `df` (as text so it can be copy-pasted)

Answer (score 2):

You try to sum strings, which will then concatenate them.
Try using aggfunc='count', it should work :)

Edit: You can add a temporary column set to 1 for it to be the structure you want:

```py
pivot = df.assign(val=1).pivot_table(values='val', index='Favorite_Music_Genre', columns='Gender', aggfunc='count')
```

Comment: Actually I suppose I should clarify, I am trying to display the number of each sex that prefers a specific music genre, so rather than a total count it's broken down into M and F

Comment: Yop, that is what a pivot table does, but doesn't it work with count instead of sum?

Comment: count displays the total number of ppl for each genre, but it isnt broken down into sex

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
for i in range(len(df)):
    genre = df['Favorite_Music_Genre'][i]
    text  = df['Gender'][i]
    print('Number of F in',genre,'is',df['Gender'][i].count('F'))
    print('Number of M in',genre,'is',df['Gender'][i].count('M'))
```